# Right CMake way for installing shared library that depends on inner static libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following structure of my CMakeLists:

```
...
add_subdirectory(staticLibrary1)
add_subdirectory(staticLibrary2)
add_subdirectory(staticLibrary3)

add_library(sharedLibrary ...)
target_link_libraries(sharedLibrary staticLibrary1 staticLibrary2 staticLibrary3)
...
```

- **staticLibraryN** can depend on system libraries for example.
- **staticLibraryN** can provide public headers, which must be also public for **sharedLibrary**.
- **staticLibraryN** source cannot be copied into **sharedLibrary**.

---

**Q:** How to install **sharedLibrary** properly, so it can be found with `find_package()` and compiled against?

The desired result is an installation working as if all static libraries code was copied into shared library.

I know how to write target export, create config.cmake files and how to install headers. The problem is related to the dependencies transition.

---

I can think of 2 not really good ways how to do it.

**1.** (the way I'm doing it now)

I install targets of static libraries and then add `find_dependency()` for each of them in my `-config.cmake` file.

A downside of it: static libraries are installed along with **sharedLibrary**, which I don't really need. If I try to skip them, it starts to complain about missing static libs.

(Just to note, if I change them to shared libraries everything is working almost perfect.)

**2.** (I haven't tried it, but should work also)

Use generator expressions, like this:

```
target_link_libraries(sharedLibrary $<BUILD_INTERFACE:staticLibrary1> $<BUILD_INTERFACE:staticLibrary2> $<BUILD_INTERFACE:staticLibrary3>)
```

But a downside of this: I cannot gather their dependencies automatically during `find_package()` call.

I will probably need to write second time all their dependencies as `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>`. Maybe it is even more inconvenient than the first approach.

Comment: You may run into problems if the static libraries are not compiled with `-fPIC`. Normally you'll want to avoid mixing static and shared libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by `I cannot gather their dependencies automatically during find_package() call.`

Comment: Static libraries are built with `POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON`, so it's ok.

By `I cannot gather their dependencies automatically during find_package() call.`, I mean that usually target provides it's dependencies. But in the last example IMPORTED library won't have target dependencies, so I need to use `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>`.